# How can I receive a "form-data" from Angular in my ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: postman, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data

I have been trying to resolve this but I couldn't find an answer.

I have this ASP.NET Core Web API endpoint in C#:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/CartaPorte/sendFormData")]
public IActionResult sendPDF([FromForm] FormDataModel formData)
{
    try
    {
        var ruta = formData.Ruta; 
        var archivo = formData.PDFContent; 

        return (IActionResult)BadRequest();
    } 
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        return (IActionResult)BadRequest();
    }
}
```

FormDataModel:

```
public class FormDataModel
{
    public string Ruta { get; set; }
    public IFormFile PDFContent { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to send my form-data in Postman I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq0M3.png)

> This resource does not support the 'multipart/form-data' media type of the request entity

I don't have any idea how I can resolve this. I hope you can help me

Comment: Try and change the form encryption from multipart form data to some other encryption and retry

Comment: Hi! when i use another format like "w-www-form-urlencoded" i receive my datas with no problems, but, i need to receive a pdf file, thats the reason what i need form-data @VibrantWaves

Comment: I try your code and send your form-data in Postman , it's ok. What's your title "How can I receive a "form-data" from Angular "  mean ?